# findViewById in specific layout?

Tags: android

Instead of prefixing id's in xml, is it possible to specify the particular layout in code? For example, if I have 3 layouts, each with a button that has an id of "btn". Is it possible to specify which layout to findViewById(R.id.btn) in?

Comment: it will search that id in the one that you inflated via inflate or setcontentView

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic context is defined via `setContentView(R.lyaout.my_layout)`. If you inflate another layout using `LayoutInflater.inflate()` you get a layout object, lets call it `buttonLayout`. You can now differ between `this.findViewById(R.id.button)` and `buttonLayout.findViewById(R.id.button)` and both will give you different button references.

Answer (score 3):

`findViewById` is a method of the `View` class. You can specify where the view should be searched for like that

```
final View container = new View(context); 
container.findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

Comment: it is also a method of the `Activity` class

Answer (score 0):

If your content view is a complex hierarchy that has several views with id `btn`, you will need to navigate to a subtree of the hierarchy and search from there. Suppose you have three `LinearLayout` views, each with a `btn` view somewhere in it. If you can first select the correct `LinearLayout` (by id, tag, position, or some other means), you can then find the correct `btn` view. If the relevant `LinearLayout` has id of `branch1`, for instance:

```
View parent = findViewById(R.id.branch1); // Activity method
View btn = parent.findViewById(R.id.btn); // View method
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have your btns inside different Viewgroups, it is possible, but requires to give ViewGroups a different name! Easyiest will be for that purpose to define the Layout of the Button inside its own XML (i.e button_layout.xml)
inside your Activity you can do this:

```
public MyActivity extends Activity{

  Button btn1, btn2, btn3;

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
    setContentView(ll);

    btn1 = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_layout, ll);
    btn2 = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_layout, ll);
    btn3 = (Button)inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_layout, ll);

  }
}
```